# How to use Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing on Distinct datetime

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data like below

```
---------------------------------------------------|
|Id      |     DateTime                | products  |
|--------|-----------------------------|-----------|
|       1| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000| 1         |  
|       1| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000| 2         |
|       1| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000| 3         |
|       1| 2016-05-24T00:00:00.000+0000| 1         |
```

I am using `window.unboundedPreceding` , `window.unboundedFollowing` as below to get the second recent datetime.

```
sorted_times = Window.partitionBy('Id').orderBy(F.col('ModifiedTime').desc()).rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding,Window.unboundedFollowing)
df3 = (data.withColumn("second_recent",F.collect_list(F.col('ModifiedTime')).over(sorted_times)).getItem(1)))
```

But I get the results as below,getting the second date from second row which is same as first row

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Id      |DateTime                     | secondtime                   |Products        
|--------|-----------------------------|----------------------------- |--------------
|       1| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000 | 1
|       1| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000 | 2
|       1| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000 | 3
|       1| 2016-05-24T00:00:00.000+0000| 2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000 | 1
```

Please help me in finding the second latest datetime on distinct datetime.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your question correctly. Learn how to add a table to your question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501/17554728).

Answer (score 1):

Use `collect_set` instead of `collect_list` for no duplicates:

```
df3 = data.withColumn(
    "second_recent",
    F.collect_set(F.col('LastModifiedTime')).over(sorted_times)[1]
)

df3.show(truncate=False)
#+-----+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------+
#|VipId|LastModifiedTime            |products|second_recent               |
#+-----+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------+
#|1    |2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000|1       |2016-05-24T00:00:00.000+0000|
#|1    |2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000|2       |2016-05-24T00:00:00.000+0000|
#|1    |2017-08-24T00:00:00.000+0000|3       |2016-05-24T00:00:00.000+0000|
#|1    |2016-05-24T00:00:00.000+0000|1       |2016-05-24T00:00:00.000+0000|
#+-----+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------+
```

---

Another way by using unordered window and sorting the array before taking `second_recent`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df3 = data.withColumn(
    "second_recent",
    F.sort_array(
        F.collect_set(F.col('LastModifiedTime')).over(Window.partitionBy('VipId')),
        False
    )[1]
)
```